# Java Unzip each file into Database

Tags: java, zip

I am attempting to write a java application that will unzip an archive and store it in a database.

I would like to insert each file in the database after it has been extracted, does anyone have a good example of a java unzip procedure?

Comment: Google might have a good example or two

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little google-search would have helped you. [Tutorial by Sun](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/compression/).

If you want to store the extracted data in a MySQL-Database you'll want to use a BLOB to do so. Tutorial might be found [here](http://www.javangelist.de/space/JDBC/Blob).

**Notice:** BLOBs should not grow bigger then 1M because they'll be slower then a normal file-system. [Here is the full article](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/?id=64525).

Comment: The article in question is SQL-server specific. Each database handles BLOBs differently.

Comment: The linked Tutorial for Blobs is also SQL-specific. I was guessing he uses MySQL, if this is not the case, I'll remove/edit it.